# Nginx with laravel custom header not working

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have a laravel application in which I need to get the ip address from x-forwaded-for instead of getClientIp() method but the problem is I am not being able to set x-forwaded-for header with ip in nginx . Below is my nginx configuration

```
server {

listen 9003;
listen [::]:9003;
# Log files for Debugging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/immigration-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/immigration-error.log;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 10000;
   # Webroot Directory for Laravel project
    root /var/www/backend/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Your Domain Name
    server_name *****;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header x-forwaded-for  "test";
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

# PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
    location ~ \.php$ {


        try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
             fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

and below is the laravel code

```
    public function test()
{
    $ip = request()->header('x-forwarded-for');
    dd($ip)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `fastcgi_param X_FORWARDED_FOR "test";` instead of `proxy_set_header x-forwaded-for  "test";`. `proxy_set_header` directive works with [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)